# Bulma CSS columns reversed on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

I have a line around which I want Bulma CSS columns to act as "leaves" on a "tree".
I am achieving this with `<div>` elements from top to bottom, with two columns each so they take up the left and right side of the screen. Text is then left/right aligned.
The top 4 buttons should be on the right side, the bottom 4 on the left.

Here is a graphic of what I mean:
[Working on Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71eQA.png)

However, when the screen width gets too small i.e. mobile browser, the columns break and it seems text alignment is reversed:
[Broken on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOhte.png)

My format is essentially:

```
//div structure for a top right "leaf"

<div class="columns">
    <div class="column"></div> //empty left side column
    <div class="column">
        <button class="button"> Hello </button>
    </div>
</div>

//empty column divs in the middle section for spacing
...

//div structure for a bottom left "leaf"
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column has-text-right">
        <button class="button">Hello</button>
    </div>
        <div class="column"></div> //empty right side column
</div>
```

Any idea why this is breaking?

In case it's helpful, here's a screenshot of my very repetitive CSS structure for this tree. [Tree divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko27W.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because by default columns in Bulma aren‘t activated on mobile (which is up to `768px`, the different sizes in Bulma are visible in [the documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/visibility-helpers/#hide)), so they are stacked on top of each other.

The solution is to add the `is-mobile` class to your `columns` containers so your example looks like this:

```
//div structure for a top right "leaf"

<div class="columns is-mobile">  // is-mobile class added
    <div class="column"></div> //empty left side column
    <div class="column">
        <button class="button"> Hello </button>
    </div>
</div>

//empty column divs in the middle section for spacing
...

//div structure for a bottom left "leaf"
<div class="columns is-mobile">  // is-mobile class added
    <div class="column has-text-right">
        <button class="button">Hello</button>
    </div>
        <div class="column"></div> //empty right side column
</div>
```

You can check [this part of the documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/#mobile-columns) for more details about mobile columns.